# Fetch events data into Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-api, firebase-analytics

We have two apps for iOS and Android on Firebase.

I linked Firebase Analytics with Google Analytics. I can see all logged events in both Firebase and Google Analytics consoles, but I can't get events through Google Analytics API.

How can I fetch events data collected with Firebase Analytics into Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics are completely separated products. Linking them toghether allows you to see your firebase reports in the Google Analytics UI, but the data and reports themselves are still different and separated.

The Google Analytics API won't allow you to query any of your data in Firebase Analytics. There's no API to query data from Firebase Analytics programatically.

Your option to query this data programmatically is to [link your Firebase Analytics with BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en). This will allow you to get Firebase Analytics data exported into BigQuery which in turn you can query using different BigQuery Tools.

Comment: BigQuery there are API for fetching data ?

Comment: @KisinPavel yes there is a BigQuery api with client libraries in different languages and even a Command-line tool